# Writing problem with ttyAMA0 in termios

Tags: uart, raspi-config

I want to use serial port of my raspberry (version 3) in order to communicate with the PC. It is my code, borrowed from http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/uart-serial-port/using-the-uart:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>                     //Used for UART
#include <fcntl.h>                      //Used for UART
#include <termios.h>            //Used for UART

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int fd, retv;
        struct termios options;
        char str[10]="hello";

        if (argc != 2)
        {
                fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s /dev/ttyx\n", argv[0]);
                exit (1);
        }

        fd = open (argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
        if (fd < 0)
        {
                perror ("Serial file couldn't be opend !");
                return -1;
        }

        tcgetattr(fd, &options);
        options.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;               //<Set baud rate
        options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
        options.c_oflag = 0;
        options.c_lflag = 0;
        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

        retv = write(fd, str, strlen(str));
        printf ("Sent bytes: %d\n", retv);

        return 0;
}
```

When i set console-on-serial in raspi-config, I can see serial output. So RPI's serial port is OK. I have turn off serial console via raspi-config due to the serial access conflict, but i can't send anything. 
Above code work fine when i use some usb-to-serial device. Example:

```
pi@RPI:~$./test /dev/ttyUSB0 
Sent bytes: 5
```

However, I can't send any byte on ttyAMA0:

```
pi@RPI:~$./test /dev/ttyAMA0 
Sent bytes: 0
```

Why it doesn't work with ttyAMA0?

Comment: See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Raspberry Pi 3 model, it's a bit more complex.There are two UARTs. The **ttyAMA0** is used for Bluetooth. There is another uart to the **ttyS0**, which is connected to the GPIO pins.

Check this link for more informations.
http://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/

Related questions
[How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)
[UART problems on my Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47379/uart-problems-on-my-pi3)