# System doesn't discover bluetooth adapter

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, buildroot

I have custom buildroot image built for Raspberry Pi Zero W. My primary goal is to be able to activate on-board blueetoth, however I seem to have
immense problems achieving it. My main problem is that no matter what I do my system cannot detect any bluetooth adapters.

My buildroot .config:
https://github.com/KarolPWr/Bluetooth-buildroot-rpi/blob/master/.config

Releveant part of config.txt:

```
# fixes rpi3 ttyAMA0 serial console
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

# enable rpi3 ttyS0 serial console
enable_uart=1
```

cmdline.txt:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootwait console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200
```

What I do after boot finishes:

```
modprobe hci_uart
rfcomm
bluetoothd
```

All starts without errors. Then when I type `bt-device -l`, no adapter is shown.

When executing command  `hciattach /dev/ttyS0 any 921600 noflow -` I get informed of several bluetooth timeouts and then I only get:

```
# hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
        TX bytes:12 acl:0 sco:0 commands:3 errors:0
```

I also tried `hciattach /dev/ttyS0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow -`
But this fails with `Unknown device type or id`

I've already spent many hours researching various resources, but I still feel very lost.

As a sidenote, I'd like to preserve serial console on GPIO pins, since its very useful for debugging. 
For now I have no idea how to make this configuration work.

Comment: Have you seen https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47284/pi3-and-mini-uart-bt - there is also an old note in `dtoverlay -h pi3-miniuart-bt` that said *It is also necessary to edit /lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service and replace ttyAMA0 with ttyS0* Not sure if either of these are a fix for you with the custom build.

Comment: @Andyroo Thanks for the link, I adjusted my config.txt. However it did not change much. Like you said, I'm not using systemd so I cant configure hciuart like this. It is also strange for me that hciattach does not allow me to use 'bcm43xx' argument. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just wondered if you need to use bluetoothctl and issue a `power on` command?  There was a quirk back in Jessie where this was required...